# Getting sshd to use a proxy when tunneling with SOCKS5

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel

I have a setup (which I cannot change), in which I need to a access a webserver from my local machine. I don't have direct access to the webserver. It is only accessible from a proxy. The proxy however, is only accessible from a jump host (which I can access with SSH).

```
+------------+   SOCKS5      +-----------+   HTTP    +-------+  HTTP  +-----------+
| My browser | ------------> | Jump Host |---------> | Proxy | -----> | Webserver |
+------------+   via ssh     +-----------+   Proxy   +-------+        +-----------+
```

I can successfully create a SOCKS5 tunnel to the jump host with `ssh -N -D 9090 username@jumphost` and by telling my browser to user SOCKS5 at localhost:9090.

However, I can't use the HTTP proxy with the SOCKS5 tunnel. I guess sshd on the Jump Host would need to be told to make HTTP(S) requests with the Proxy. I can't find this setting anywhere. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess sshd on the Jump Host would need to be told to make HTTP(S) requests with the Proxy. I can't find this setting anywhere.

There isn't one, because sshd does not make or understand HTTP(S) requests.

It only makes TCP connections, which in theory *could* be proxied in a generic way using HTTP CONNECT (the same way HTTPS requests are proxied, actually), but there's no such feature in OpenSSH sshd.

> Is this even possible?

Drop the SOCKS5 part and have your browser directly talk to the remote HTTP proxy via SSH.

You are creating the SOCKS5 tunnel between your browser and your SSH **client** – *not* between browser and the sshd; over the network, it's indistinguishable from statically defined `-L` tunnels. So you might as well just set up a `-L` tunnel for the HTTP(S) proxy instead:

1. `$ ssh -N -L 9080:the_proxy:8080 jumphost`
2. `HTTP Proxy: [localhost] Port: [9080]`